# Sort Array of Map by one of values in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have `Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]` and I need to sort them by the 2nd value `"v2"` and return a same Array of Map

```
 val col = Array(Map("key" -> Array("aa","bb"), "v1" -> 1 , "v2" -> 3),Map("key" -> Array("cc","bb"), "v1" -> 2 , "v2" -> 4))
```

I have done the following:

```
scala> col sortBy {col("v2")}
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("v2")
 required: Int
          col sortBy {col("v2")}
```

or this

```
scala> col sortWith {col("v2") > col("v2")}
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
found   : String("v2")
 required: Int
          col sortWith {col("v2") < col("v2")}
```

and I don't understand what does it mean `required: Int` and how to sort this `Array[Map[String,Any]`!!

**Edit :**

I tried as well

```
scala> col.toSeq.sortWith(col("v2").trim().toDouble >    col("v2").trim().toDouble)
 <console>:32: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("v2")
 required: Int
```

Comment: Your `Map` values are of type `Any`. How you have the compiler sort values of that type?

Comment: check edited part @Yuval

Answer (score 1):

Your collections are `Map[String, Any]`, not `Map[String, Int]`, so the compiler doesn't know that the items it is getting are comparable `Int`s.  The easiest thing would probably be to use `asInstanceOf[Int]` to cast it to something that you can sort.

`col sortBy {_("v2").asInstanceOf[Int]}`

However, the unrelated values suggests a logistical problem; using a custom class rather than a plain `Map` is probably better for this case and will remove the need to cast anything.

Comment: Thank you @James , I got the idea , but still have compilation error : `scala> col sortWith {col("v2").asInstanceOf[Int]}
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("v2")
 required: Int
              col sortWith {col("v2").asInstanceOf[Int]}`

Comment: That's what happens when I don't actually test things.  The inner `col` should be the loop argument (changed in the answer above).  It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work by doing an explicit casting of v2 value to Int (assuming that v2 will always be an Int):

```
col.sortWith(_.getOrElse("v2",0).asInstanceOf[Int] > _.getOrElse("v2",0).asInstanceOf[Int])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coupons: Seq[mutable.Map[String, String]]

coupons.sortBy(X => X.get("timestamp")).toSeq
```

Will get you the sorted seq by the value corresponding to map.

eg : Input:  `Array(Map(timestamp-> 1522233333, coupon_status -> O),Map(timestamp-> 1522211111, coupon_status -> C))`

Output: `Array(Map(timestamp-> 1522211111, coupon_status -> C),Map(timestamp-> 1522233333, coupon_status -> O))`